# Regex / Javascript - How to remove() a URL from http:// to TLD

Tags: javascript, regex

My Regex doesn't work :

-- Without modifiers removing "https://www." in the console works. But I want more.
-- With especially groups ([a-zA-Z]+ and/or modifier (+?),  my original string is not matched.

WORKS query = https://www.
DOESN'T WORK https://www.[a-zA-Z]+.
DOESN'T WORK https?://www.

Sample string :

```
var text = `
hi max, I have a big link to share, it's https://www.test.com/?q=what&sz=48x48. 
What do you think ?
`;
```

WORKS

```
text = text
    .replace("max","bob")
    .replace('https://www\.',"");
```

DOESN'T WORK

````
    .replace("max","bob")
    .replace('https?://www\.[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/?',"");```
````

Comment: Why do you want to do this with regex? You can just parse the URL and get the parts of it you need.

Comment: I don't want any part of a URL.

Comment: "*I want to remove everything up to the TLD + optional trailing /. I don't mind keeping the rest.*"

Comment: I don't mind doesn't mean I want it. For my requirements I wanted to get rid of at least everything up to the TLD/, I've seen Regex that does that but that was not the point, the point was my syntax with the quotes didn't work; Anthony below pointed out that I needed to use the / / syntax. Don't know why the quote comes up so often (I'm a newbie if that wasn't clear) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right syntax:

```js
text.replace(/https?:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/?/,"");
```

Although there are other issues with this code (not all domains starts with www etc).

Comment: www was for testing and it's there only because [a-zA-Z]+ or [a-zA-Z]\.? didn't work for the subdomain.

Comment: You showed me the right / / syntax without the single quote, that was the issue, many thanks !